# Why use an the address of a variable to multiply another variable?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double principal = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    double rate = strtod(argv[2], NULL);

    invest(&principal, rate);

    printf("%.2f\n", principal);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the start code given in some exercise. We are going to write a function that multiplies the principal with the rate. I don't understand why the first argument is an address of a variable and the second argument is a variable in the function `invest`. They both initiate as variables. Why we don't put variables in both arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "put a variable as argument", you pass the value of the variable. All of C's argument passing is by value.

`invest` needs to **modify** `principal` to hold another value, as evident by the fact its value is being printed after the call to the function. How can it do that if all it was given is just a copy of the original value stored in `principal`?

That's why the first argument it accepts is a pointer. `main` passes that **address** of `principal`, and so `invest` can modify the variable itself.

Comment: So in this case, both `&principal` and `rate` are values while the pointer `&principal` acts like an intermediate variable?

Comment: @user8314628 - In the declaration of `invest` there will need to be a pointer parameter (`double *pInvest`, for instance). That is the intermediate variable that holds an *address*, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever an argument is passed to a function, the function receives a copy of it.  Nothing the function can do with that copy will affect the original.  In order for information to be passed from a function to its caller, one of two things has to happen.  Either the function needs to return the value, or the function has to put it someplace the caller can find it.  A pointer serves to identify an object from which information may be written or to which it may be read.  I would expect that the `invest()` function is intended to read the value identified by the passed-in pointer (i.e. in this case read `principal`, then perform some computations, and then store the result back to that same object (again, `principal`).